# Keeping button state on page refresh?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a like button on my index.php page that increments and changes to "Liked" when clicked. Which is great. Problem is, when I reload the page, the "Liked" button goes back to its original "Like" state.

My question is, how do I keep the button as "Liked" even on a page refresh?

I'm assuming that in my `likes` table I would have to set `liked_unliked` to '1' when the button is clicked. But how would the JQuery that changes the state of the like button know that there is a '1' meaning that the user has already clicked 'Like' on that image, which would keep the "Liked" state even on page refresh?

Here is my index.php :

```
<!doctype html>
<?php
session_start();
?>
<html>
<head>

<?php
    include('header.php');
?>

<script>
//send info to like_button.php then to DB
$(document).ready(function(){
 $(".button").click(function(){
  $.ajax({url:"liked_button.php",success:function(result){
  //do nothing
  }});
 });
});
//change like button when clicked
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".button").click(function(){
    var t=$(this);
         t.replaceWith("<button type='button' class='button_pressed'>Liked</button>");
     });
});
//increment like counter when button is clicked
function increase(t) { 
 t=$(t).parent().next(); 
     t.val(parseInt(t.val())+1); 
}
</script>

</head>
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">
<body>

<?php
//dispay the images that the users upload
$conn = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","") or die ("No SQLI");
    mysqli_select_db($conn, "sample") or die ("No DB");

$sqli = "SELECT * FROM `photos` ORDER BY `id` DESC";

$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sqli) or die ("No query");

while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))    

{
$username = $row['username'];
$title = $row['title'];
$description = $row['description'];
$image_name = $row['image_name'];
$image_id = $row['image_id'];
$random_directory = $row['random_direc'];
$date = date('Y-m-d');

 $image_info = "http://localhost/splindr_2.0/photos/$random_directory/$image_name";
 //echo all content in content wrapper
 echo "<div id=contentWrapper'>
          <div class='photo'>
              <div class='actual_image'>
                 <img src='$image_info'>
              </div>          
              <div class='like_system'><button onClick='increase(this)' type='button' class='button' id='button' name='button'>Like</button></div> 
                                       <input type='text' name='total_likes' id='total_likes' value='0'>
                                       <div class='twitter'><button type='button'  class='twitter_button' name='twitter_button' id='twitter_button'>
                                                            <a style='color: #2e4987;text-decoration:none' href='http://www.twitter.com/share?url=$image_info&hashtags=Splindr, CheckThisOut'>Share On Twitter</a></button>
                                       </div>
                                       <div class='trash_bin'>
                                          <button type='button' class='delete_button' name='delete_button' id='delete_button'>
                                             <a style='text-decoration:none;color: #2e4987' href='delete_post.php'>Delete</a>
                                          </button>
                                       </div>
                    <div class='info_wrapper'>
                       <div class='info_header'>Title: $title &nbsp By: $username &nbsp   Date: $date</div>
                           <div class='description'>$description</div>
                    </div>
              </div>
          </div>
      </div>";//end contentWrapper

}

?> 

</body>
</html>
```

My `likes` table:

```
CREATE TABLE if not exists `likes` (
     `id` int(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
     `image_id` varchar(300) NOT NULL,
     `liked_by` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
     `liked_unliked` enum('0','1') NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
      PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
```

Comment: Do you users log in? Or this is a website without login and many anonymous users can click the button? You can use cookies or sessions for storing the previous state of website, but this can be easily avoided by cleaning the cookies.

Comment: this does have a login site where users' info is stored in the `users` table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are keeping track of who pressed the like button I assume in the liked_by field. You can add the user's likes to the session. That way if you refresh the page you have the user_id in the likes session and adjust your css for the button accordingly.

```
    <?php
   $_SESSION['likes'] = array(
      'img1' => 'user2, user3',
      'img2' => 'user2',
      'img3' => 'user2','user5',
     );

    $likes = $_SESSION['likes'] ;

    foreach($likes as $key => $like){
       $likeArray = explode(',', $like); //convert string of user ids to array

      if(in_array($userId, $likeArray)){
        //user has like image with id $key
      }else{
       //user has not
      }

     }
     ?>
```

Comment: @chikurubi how this would work for multiple images on the index.php page? The index.php page has multiple images all with unique image ID's. Let me know if you need any further explanation.

Comment: ok if you have multiple images you can use a multi-dimensional array or have a string of user IDs for each image ID

Comment: Sorry about this but I'm what you'd call 'wet behind the ears' when it comes to PHP. Perhaps you wouldn't mind explaining that a little more?

Comment: okay I see that you have 'img 1, img 2, img 3, and user1,user2,user5. What if I wanted this array to apply for any image or user in the DB...depending on which user is liking which image?

Comment: When the user logs in you need to store their id in a session. Like $_SESSION['user_id'] which you can use in place of $userId. And when you go to a page you need to get the likes for each image and store them in a variable of $likes. You don't necessarily have to store the $likes in a session if you are Querying for the data on each page refresh/load. Does that make sense?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/54740/discussion-between-ralston3-and-chikurubhi).